# I-text Pdf table supported greek character fonts

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, itext

i would like to ask you if any of the already existing itext fonts supports greek characters because whatever i have tried so far failed by displaying weird characters. I have also tried to use a windows font and then worked fine. But preferrably i would like to use one of the Standard Type 1 for flexibility reasons. Is there any possibility for that or only by other locations?

Comment: You are probably using the wrong terminology. When you say "I would like to use one of the embedded ones", you probably mean that you want to use the Standard Type 1 fonts that are not embedded. Can you adapt your question so that this is more clear for people wanting to answer the question?

Comment: Yes i mean the Standard Type 1 fonts. i would like to use one of these fonts if it is possible than creating a new one.

Comment: None of the regular "Base Fonts" *except* for Symbol contain Greek. Symbol is sufficient for basic Greek symbols in math expressions only -- it lacks bold and italics. For Greek typesetting you need an external font.